# Cannot hide MBProgressHUD in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I tried this code to show `MBProgressHUD` but when I click on another tab and back to this tab, `MBProgressHUD` cannot hide. I tried this for 2 functions:

For `updatearray()`

```
 MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading..";
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
{
[self updatearray];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
[hud hide:YES];
});
});
```

for getVideolist()

```
 MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading..";
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
    {
    [self getVideolist];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [hud hide:YES];
    });
    });
```

In first time, it runs ok. But after click on another tab and back, it cannot hide.

Comment: Did the `[self updatearray];` finish loading ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Yes, it finish loading. I've been updated my question. Pls check out. thanks

Comment: handle exception if there any error. if there any see what is it.

Comment: It does not have error. I don't know why it can not hide.

Comment: how you sure about that . have you put try catch block to check it?

Comment: Advice: Use `MBProgressHUDDelegate` .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Can you example code? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your `MBProgressHUD` a private property (strong, nonatomic). Then you can reference the same instance of your progress hud in other methods or threads and update or hide it.